# Resolve conflict in saved games: await must not be called on UI thread

Tags: android, google-play-services, illegalstateexception

I'm using Saved Games API in a similar way to the Collect All The Stars 2 sample provided with the API https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/#samples.

When saving a game the following method is called:

```
/**
 * Prepares saving Snapshot to the user's synchronized storage, conditionally resolves errors,
 * and stores the Snapshot.
 */
void saveSnapshot() {
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult> task =
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult>() {
                @Override
                protected Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult result = Games.Snapshots.open(getApiClient(),
                            currentSaveName, true).await();
                    return result;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult result) {
                    Snapshot toWrite = processSnapshotOpenResult(result, 0);

                    Log.i(TAG, writeSnapshot(toWrite));
                }
            };

    task.execute();
}
```

So the snapshot is opened in a background thread and when it's finished it comes back to UI thread and calls `processSnapshotOpenResult(result,0)`, which contains the following line:

```
        Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult resolveResult = Games.Snapshots.resolveConflict(
                getApiClient(), result.getConflictId(), mResolvedSnapshot)
                .await();
```

Which in the case of conflict gives an IllegalStateException (taken from my implementation, not from CollectAllTheStars2):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: await must not be called on the UI thread
at com.google.android.gms.internal.hn.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.a$a.await(Unknown Source)
at com.xxx.SaveGame.processSnapshotOpenResult(SaveGame.java:301)
at com.xxx.SaveGame$2.onPostExecute(SaveGame.java:412)
at com.xxx.SaveGame$2.onPostExecute(SaveGame.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4746)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:917)
```

So it seems there's a bug in the sample, unless I missed something.. And anyway, how to resolve this? Maybe the `processSnapshotOpenResult` should be put in another AsyncTask? However it calls itself recursively so the brain's starting to boil and more exceptions are likely to come. Here is the complete source:

https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/CollectAllTheStars2/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/catt2/MainActivity.java

Comment: yes, you missed something ... await must **not** be called on the UI thread so processSnapshotOpenResult should be also called in doInBackground

Comment: yes, I know that, @Selvin, but that's how it is implemented in the official sample app, so if it is a bug, it is a bug in the official sample app.. unless we're missing something more subtle.. i'm working on a workaround anyway, thanks;)

Answer (score 0):

Using the LoadFromSnapshot method in the stars games as an example, I re-wrote the savesnapshot method to handle processSnapshotOpenResult in the background and to pass the snapshot object to postExecute:

```
void saveSnapshot(final SnapshotMetadata snapshotMetadata, final String currentSaveName) {

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Snapshot> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Snapshot>() {
        @Override
        protected Snapshot doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult result;
            if (snapshotMetadata != null && snapshotMetadata.getUniqueName() != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Opening snapshot by metadata: " + snapshotMetadata);
                result = Games.Snapshots.open(mGamesClient, snapshotMetadata).await();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Opening snapshot by name: " + currentSaveName);
                result = Games.Snapshots.open(mGamesClient, currentSaveName, true).await();
            }

            int status = result.getStatus().getStatusCode();

            Snapshot snapshot = null;
            if (status == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
                snapshot = result.getSnapshot();
            } else if (status == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_SNAPSHOT_CONFLICT) {

                // if there is a conflict  - then resolve it.
                snapshot = processSnapshotOpenResult(result, 0);

                // if it resolved OK, change the status to Ok
                if (snapshot != null) {
                    status = GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK;
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Conflict was not resolved automatically");
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error while loading: " + status);
            }

            return snapshot;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Snapshot toWriteSnapshot) {

            if (toWriteSnapshot != null) {

                    writeSnapshot(toWriteSnapshot, data, desccription);

            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error opening snapshot.");
            }

        }
    };

    task.execute();
}
```